# How to mark end of dataset in android paging 3 library?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-paging, android-paging-library

I am trying to use Android new Paging 3 Library in my app. I am fetching data from a backend API using Retrofit, which returns a list of objects. I need to know how to inform Pager to stop loading more data when the API returns an empty list.

Comment: Hey Arpit, we'd love to hear if you can give us some more context to your problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you have empty list, you should return `nextKey = null` in `LoadResult.Page(...)` to the Paging3 will know that there is no data further to load